# Want to make both the background image and color overly responsive

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive

I'm developing PSD to Wordpress and facing problems with aligning a background image with respect to color overly, or the other way around.

On desktop everything is good but on mobile the background image becomes small (I used `background-size: 100%;`). The color overly remains the same, which ruins everything on small devices.

What's going wrong?

```css
.section-bg-image1 {
  padding: 100px 0px 300px 0px;
  background: url("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/section_image2.png") no-repeat left bottom;
  position: relative;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.layer {
  background-color: rgba(226, 258, 62, 0.53);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="section-bg-image1">
      <div class="layer">
        <p class="section-bg-image1-paragraph">Some content goes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without more context. Please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Tijmen  
here is html <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-6"> <div class="section-bg-image1"> <div class="layer"> <p class="section-bg-image1-paragraph">Some content goes here</p> </div> </div> </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do width and not background size. and try to do a max-width of 100% also. I can't help a lot more because this code is limited and only CSS. Can you provide some HTML also?

Comment: here is html <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="section-bg-image1">
        <div class="layer">
        <p class="section-bg-image1-paragraph">Some content goes here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

Comment: Perfect. :) Did you use width: 100%?

Comment: I just Removed Background-size and That's all